# A good book for fiber bundle, induced bundle, whitney sums

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I was reading these topics from Bredon's Topology and Geometry book but I am not understanding properly these concepts. Please tell me some basic book for fibre bundle, induced bundle, whitney sums etc. I also want to mention that I am a beginner in this subject. Thanks

Comment: I recommend the book on algebraic topology by Allen Hatcher.

Comment: Take a look at Husemoller's "Fiber bundles".